# Making pictures look inset

Tags: graphics, quartz-graphics, image

I wonder if anyone has an idea how you have to transform an image such that it looks "inset" to the context?

I need the effect for an application I am writing, but I am not sure what the exact workflow is to achieve the effect mentioned above.

Best regards,
heinrich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've made it. 
It is much playing around with paths and those stuff ...